# How do I build a grouped bar chart with scaleTime, using D3.js?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, graph, charts, data-visualization

I`m trying to do a grouped barchart using D3, I just make it with scaleBand, but now I need to do with scaleTime. Thats my code with scaleBand:

```
const x0 = scaleBand().range([0, innerWidth]).paddingInner(0.5);

      const x1 = scaleBand().padding(0);

      const y = scaleLinear().range([innerHeight, 0]);

      x0.domain(allGroups);
      x1.domain(subgroups).range([0, x0.bandwidth()]);
      y.domain([0, maxValue]).nice();

      graph
        .append("g")
        .selectAll("g")
        .data(data)
        .enter()
        .append("g")
        .attr("class", "bar")
        .attr("transform", (d) => `translate(${x0(d.key)},0)`)
        .selectAll("rect")
        .data((d) =>
          d.data.map((e) => {
            return { key: d.key, name: e.name, value: e.value };
          })
        )
        .enter()
        .append("rect")
        .attr("x", (d) => x1(d.name))
        .attr("y", (d) => y(d.value))
        .attr("width", x1.bandwidth())
        .attr("height", (d) => innerHeight - y(d.value))
        .attr("fill", (d) => color(d.name))

      graph
        .append("g")
        .attr("transform", `translate(0,${innerHeight})`)
        .call(axisBottom(x0));

      graph.append("g").call(axisLeft(y));
```

I tried to change only the 'x0' to scaleTime but it overlaps the bars and doesn't position them correctly

Comment: Why are you changing it from band to time? Band is a natural choice for a bar chart as each item in the domain has width. Times do not have widths - they are points on a continuous domain and time periods, such as days, weeks, months, or years, do not have equal duration, and if duration is equal to width, can mean bars of unequal width. While the above applies to basic bar charts, band is also a natural choice for grouped charts in general.

Comment: Oh, I see... Thank you Andrew, I'll keep it with scaleBand then.

Answer (score 0):

Try this example:

```
let x = d3
        .scaleTime()
        .domain([(date.setFullYear(d3.min(years).getFullYear() - 1)), (date.setFullYear(d3.max(years).getFullYear()))])
        .range([0, (width - margin.left - margin.right)])

let x1 = d3.scaleBand()
        .domain(keys)
        .rangeRound([0, 147])
        .padding(0.05)
```